# How to input the current time into a mysql table from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp

I'm using a mysql_query() in PHP to insert a value into a table in a database.  One of the attributes of that table is "timestamp" which is supposed to be the current time that the query was made.  How can I generate this?  I tried using "time()" in PHP, but this is not inserting correctly in the query.  When I insert what the time() function generates, it shows up as a default in my table, as: "0000-00-00 00:00:00".  How can I generate the current time in order to input it into my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your query, you need to set the value of that field to [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) which is MySQL's function for getting a timestamp of the current time.

If you put your actual query in your question, I can help you with a more specific answer ;)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I was able to get my query working it.  I'll post it here for anyone else with a similar question:
$query_format = "insert into Review values ('%s', NOW(), %d, %d, '%s')";
    $query = sprintf($query_format, $user_name, $movie, $score, $review);

Answer (score 1):

```
insert into table (datetime_field) values (now())
```

php function time() returns a unix timestamp that it's an integer value.

Comment: Calculating the timestamp directly in MySQL is much more efficient because it doesn't require the overhead of creating variables and concatenating strings.

Answer (score 0):

Go to php.net and view the codes for getting date and time and check whether you typed the codes correctly. If you did, then check if the format you are using in your code is similar to the one you are using in your table.